# Expected value of function of Gaussian CDF, multivariate case

Tags: probability, analysis

I know this question has been answered for a single variate case Gaussian random variable, but I cannot seem to find answer where there is a Gaussian vector involved.

My question is the following, assume we have a vector of $\mathbf{V}$ of dimension $t$ of jointly Gaussian random variables  where $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ is the covariance matrix, which could be just identity. Let's say we have any function $f$, could be anything and not necessarily invertible. How can one compute the expectation in this case of:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[f(\mathbf{v})] = \int_{\mathbb{R}^t}f(\mathbf{v})p_\mathbf{V}(\mathbf{v})d\mathbf{v}
\end{align}
Can I do I try to do something iteratively like this using the tower expectation

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[f(\mathbf{v})] 
=\mathbb{E}_{v_2,\dots,v_t}[\mathbb{E}[f(v_1)|v_2,\dots,v_t]]
\end{align}

Such that $\mathbf{E}_{v_1|v_2,\dots,v_t}[f(v_1)] = \int f(v_1)p(v_1)dv_1$.
For example, would this work if $f$ is just an inner product with a deterministic vector $\mathbf{m}$? I am thinking in this particular case, since the vector is jointly Gaussian, the inner product is just another Gaussian with mean and variance $\mathbf{m}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{m}$, but I am not sure how to proceed if $f$ is not linear like this, for example if $f(\mathbf{v}) = (\mathbf{m}^T\mathbf{v})\times(\mathbf{n}^T\mathbf{v})$ where both $\mathbf{m}$ and $\mathbf{n}$ are deterministic, how would the tower expectation apply in this case?

Comment: If the dimension $t$ is larger than, say, three the best method to calculate this expectation is a Monte Carlo simulation. For $t\le 3$ a numeric integration is still reasonably fast.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(X)=X^TAX$ is quadratic and $X\sim N(m, \Sigma),$ computing $\mathbb{E}(f(X))$ is very easy. Write $X=m+\Sigma^{1/2}Z$ where $Z\sim N(0,I_n).$ You get, since $\mathbb{E}(Z)=0:$
$$\mathbb{E}(X^TAX)=m^TAm+\mathbb{E}(Z^T\Sigma^{1/2}A\Sigma^{1/2}Z)=m^TAm+\mathrm{trace}(\Sigma^{1/2}A\Sigma^{1/2})=m^TAm+\mathrm{trace}(A\Sigma).$$ If $f(X)=a^TX\times b^T X$ then $\mathbb{E}(f(X))=m^TAm+a^T\Sigma b.$

Comment: That is understandable, what if $\mathbf{f}$ is something that is not linear?